# Search haystack for several equal length needles (Python)

Tags: python

I am looking for a way to search a large string for a large number of equal length substrings.

My current method is basically this:

```
offset = 0
found = []

while offset < len(haystack):
  current_chunk = haystack[offset*8:offset*8+8]
  if current_chunk in needles:
     found.append(current_chunk)
  offset += 1
```

This is painfully slow. Is there a better python way of doing this?

Comment: How big are `haystack` and `needles` (please give some example sizes for which you want the code to work well)? Also, how likely is each chunk to be found/how many chunks are found on average in your data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More Pythonic, much faster:

```
for needle in needles:
    if needle in haystack:
        found.append(needle)
```

Edit: With some limited testing here are test results

**This algorithm:**
0.000135183334351

**Your algorithm:**
0.984048128128

Much faster.

Comment: I think you want `for needle in needles`, not for `needle in haystack` (which will iterate over the characters of `haystack` and always `find` them later). You can also use `if needle in haystack` rather than checking the return value of `find`.

Comment: Yeah, I typed it out quick, missed that here- does in implicitly use the find command eg. Does it use the same algorithm to find it?

Comment: `if needle in haystack` is more Pythonic and (usually) faster.

Comment: And the whole thing could be reduced to `found = next(filter(haystack.__contains__, needles))` (or `next(itertools.ifilter(...))` for Python 2) for what's probably the fastest.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can break it up on a multicore and parallelize your search. Something along the lines of:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

text = "Your very long string"

"""
A generator function for chopping up a given list into chunks of
length n.
"""
def chunks(l, n):
  for i in xrange(0, len(l), n):
    yield l[i:i+n]

def searchHaystack(haystack, needles):
    offset = 0
    found = []

    while offset < len(haystack):
      current_chunk = haystack[offset*8:offset*8+8]
      if current_chunk in needles:
      found.append(current_chunk)
      offset += 1
    return(needles)

# Build a pool of 8 processes
pool = Pool(processes=8,)

# Fragment the string data into 8 chunks
partitioned_text = list(chunks(text, len(text) / 8))

# Generate all the needles found
all_the_needles = pool.map(searchHaystack, partitioned_text, needles)
```